# Is there a good library for Kotlin Coroutines to access Mongo asynchronously?

Tags: mongodb, asynchronous, kotlin, nonblocking, kotlin-coroutines

I'm starting a new project in the JVM with lots of IO. At some point, I have to save some stuff in a Mongo database. My idea is to use a nonblocking approach with Kotlin coroutines.

I know there is an official reative streams driver for Mongo and the support looks good. But in this case I would need to "create bridges" between the streams and the coroutines. My question is regarding this point: does anyone know a better or simpler way of doing it?

Comment: The bridges between reactive streams and coroutines are already there. Take a look here: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/reactive. You can also read more about the relationship between reactive streams and Kotlin flows here: https://medium.com/@elizarov/reactive-streams-and-kotlin-flows-bfd12772cda4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [KMongo project](https://litote.org/kmongo). It [has](https://litote.org/kmongo/quick-start/#asynchronously-with-coroutines) coroutines support:

```kotlin
import org.litote.kmongo.reactivestreams.*  // KMongo reactivestreams extensions
import org.litote.kmongo.coroutine.* // KMongo coroutine extensions

data class Jedi(val name: String, val age: Int)

val client = KMongo.createClient().coroutine //use coroutine extension
val database = client.getDatabase("test") //normal java driver usage
val col = database.getCollection<Jedi>() //KMongo extension method

//async now
runBlocking {
    col.insertOne(Jedi("Luke Skywalker", 19))

    val yoda : Jedi? = col.findOne(Jedi::name eq "Yoda")

    (...)
}
```

Comment: Probably I am missing some conecept in Kotlin. Please, can you help me: I am getting Expecting a top level declaration in runblocking and Function declaration must have a name in col.insertOne. Kindly, can you share your complete example code ?

Comment: @JimC, check your syntax. You probably have some extra symbols in you code, that Kotlin parses didn't expect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MongoDB Kotlin driver. It supports coroutines directly and can be used in server-side applications. Here is an example:

https://www.mongodb.com/developer/products/mongodb/getting-started-kotlin-driver/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35722602)